# TopoJson makefile ignoring external properties file

Tags: csv, d3.js, topojson

I am trying to make a topojson file with csv data embedded using a makefile. I am using Mike Bostock's us-atlas as a guide.

```
topo/us-counties-10m-ungrouped.json: shp/us/counties.shp
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    topojson \
      -o us_counties.json \
      --no-pre-quantization \
      --post-quantization=1e6 \
      --external-properties=output.csv \
      --id-property=FIPS \
      --properties="County=County" \
      --properties="PerChildrenPos=+PerChildrenPos" \
      --simplify=7e-7 \
      -- $<
```

It creates the topojson I need but completely ignores the output.csv file.
Here is a glimpse at what it returns.

```
{"type":"Polygon","id":"53051","properties":{"code":"53051"},"arcs":[[-22,79,80,-75,81]]}
```

Here's what I need it to return.

```
{"type":"Polygon","id":"53051","properties":{"code":"53051", "County":"Los Angeles", "PerChildrenPos": 10},"arcs":[[-22,79,80,-75,81]]}
```

Any ideas why it might be ignoring the csv file, I've tested moving it around to see if perhaps it was unaccessible or something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation here: https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference#external-properties

> (If your CSV file uses a different column name for the feature identifier, you can specify multiple id properties, such as --id-property=+FIPS,+id.)

It seems that you need to change your `--id-property=FIPS \` to something that corresponds to your CSV column names.

Also for `--properties="County=County" \`
I think it should be `--properties County=+County \`

Same for `--properties="PerChildrenPos=+PerChildrenPos" \`
Should be `--properties PerChildrenPos=+PerChildrenPos \`

For `--external-properties=output.csv \`
it should be `--external-properties output.csv \`

Basically the parameters do not need to be prefixed by an `=` sign.

Comment: I tried these suggestions, however it still doesn't add the data like it should. Also I tried changing the id in my .csv file to FIPS for consistency sake, and it still doesn't read

Comment: Discovered that there were unnecessary spaces in the data I scraped using a custom python script. Lesson: Make sure the data matches! My fault but not in the place I thought it was. This answer also added to my successes so thank you @paradite!